# Import CSV/Excel with PHP into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, excel-2010

Have a bit of a problem with importing CSV/Excel into MYSQL and frankly not sure whether if this scenario is even possible? Sorry I don't have any code, I am just trying to get a grisp on how to do this.

Here's the drift: I have a table with 4 columns, id, userid, starttime, endtime. ID, is primary key. Starttime and Endtime are both stored as DATETIME. 
Example:

```
id    userid      starttime              endtime
1        3    2015-01-18 12:00:00  2015-01-18 16:00:00
```

I want to import a excel sheet that is laid out like this: http://tinypic.com/r/281lyd/8 (also, the start and end are columns in its own)

Questions:

1. Is this possible? If so, how?
2. If not, what are other alternative solutions to this problem? I need to somehow import weekly data into mysql database which is then outputted into a table online by week. (An admin would do this, but it should be effortless or time consuming.)

Comment: Have a look At (phpexcel)[https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/]

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan sorry, could you explain please how I could use that in my situation? Thanks for your comment

Comment: There are like a zillion usage examples for phpexcel, just google for them, or start from the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) library to import the Excel file. I don't know if you need to import xls or xlsx file, so my below source code is for xlsx. The code for xlsx file is similar. First you import the cell values into a list of rows and then insert the list values into MySQL database.

```
// Create an instance of the class that imports Excel files
$xls = new COM("EasyXLS.ExcelDocument");
    
// Import Excel file to List
$rows = $xls->easy_ReadXLSXSheet_AsList("Excel.xls", "Sheet1");

// Iterate List values
for ($rowIndex=0; $rowIndex<$rows->size(); $rowIndex++)
{
        $row = $rows->elementAt($rowIndex);
        for ($cellIndex=0; $cellIndex<$row->size(); $cellIndex++)
        {
            echo "At row ".($rowIndex + 1).", column ".($cellIndex + 1).
                        " the value is '".$row->elementAt($cellIndex)."'<br>";
            // SQL syntax to insert cell value into MySQL database: $row->elementAt($cellIndex)
            ...
        }
}
```

For more technical data, you may take a look at the following link:
http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/import-excel-to-mysql.html

To insert the data into MySQL use a similiar syntax:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

and use `$row->elementAt($cellIndex)` on VALUE section of the SQL syntax.

For importing the CSV file, you can use `easy_ReadCSVFile_AsList` in a similar way.

Comment: I have xlsx. What does this code do? How can I import the columns I have into the the columns I have my table in MYSQL? I know it would be with SQL but I have no idea how to combine it/what to write.

Comment: Please help me I am so lost, never done anything like this and I need it to be able to output stuff to users :(

Comment: Also, I have to pay for it?

Comment: Yes, I know the syntax to Insert data into MYSQL, but I am confused about the query I would have to use to somehow combine the date and time from the excel sheet to insert into the mysql table etc

Comment: yes, it is a commercial Excel library. DarkBee suggested you a free one.

Comment: This depends by how your time is stored inside the Excel file. If it is store as a date (not string) the value inside the list should be in MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: I have looked at @darkbee's solution but it doesn't support .xlsx (I think). Ahh, so confused!!!!!! That's the thing thats confusing me the most, I just don't know how to insert the date and time in same field  from excel and it should be as starttime and endtime ahhh!!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use a csv instead of a xls file you can do this you can put both the php script and the html form in one php file and it should do exactly what you need it to

**php script**

```
<?php
    session_start();

$message = null;

$allowed_extensions = array('csv');

$upload_path = 'uploadlocation';

if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {

    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {

        // check extension
        $file = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $extension = array_pop($file);

        if (in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)) {

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {

                if (($handle = fopen($upload_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'], "r")) !== false) {

                    $keys = array();
                    $out = array();

                    $insert = array();

                    $line = 1;

                    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',', '"')) !== FALSE) {

                        foreach($row as $key => $value) {
                            if ($line === 1) {
                                $keys[$key] = $value;
                            } else {
                                $out[$line][$key] = $value;

                            }
                        }

                        $line++;

                    }

                    fclose($handle);    

                    if (!empty($keys) && !empty($out)) {

                        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'root');
                        $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

                        foreach($out as $key => $value) {

                            $sql  = "INSERT INTO wherever(`";
                            $sql .= implode("`, `", $keys);
                            $sql .= "`) VALUES (";
                            $sql .= implode(", ", array_fill(0, count($keys), "?"));
                            $sql .= ")";
                            $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
                            $statement->execute($value);

                        }

                        $message = '<span color="green">File has been uploaded successfully</span>';

                    }   

                }

            }

        } else {
            $message = '<span class="red">Only .csv file format is allowed</span>';
        }

    } else {
        $message = '<span class="red">There was a problem with your file</span>';
    }

}
?>
```

**HTML Form**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table">
    <tr>
        <C><label for="file">Select file</label> <?php echo $message; ?></th>
    </tr></h2>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="30" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" id="btn" class="fl_l" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

you need to layout your excel like your database table for this code to work and you need to change the login etc for the database. Since this is Dbo it should work with all databases or atleast most of them !. If you need any help comment below

Comment: Is there a way I could upload the Excel file ( this format type spreadsheet http://tinypic.com/r/281lyd/8) and it converts the date and start time fields into one field as startime and endtime and creates a csv file like userid, starttime, endtime 
Or just have excel file upload? which does the above without converting to csv. Sorry if I am asking for too much but I generally don't know how to approach this...

Comment: if you rework your excel/csv file so that the format is compatible for the implode anything is possible. i recommend making it like this but you could make it how you like..............................   .....................                        .

`userid, username, startdate, starttime, endtime`

Comment: is there a way to merge or concatanat kind of the cells when you're inserting the values from excel? so like the startdate and starttime would become one value?

Comment: You can use a trigger in the database to do this im not sure how to do it through php

Comment: Hey, I literally had that idea last night!! I thought I could this -> insert the excel into a mysql table as it is and when its inserted i will concatanate the strings somehoew and then insert it into my actual table... don't know how to do this though...

Comment: SET NEW.date = CONCAT(LEFT(This), LEFT(this))

Comment: Something like this would help i think using CONCAT is what you want. Remember to mark question as answered if it helped !.